# SQL query not pulling all records

Tags: mysql

I have data for purchase order requisitions that are all in one row. To import them into our financial system and generate the PO I select data for each line item with a union. I created a view and it has been working great. Yesterday, I had one that didn't pull all of the line items for one PO. In researching it I took the code for the first 5 line items as that was the number of items on this request and ran the code. It didn't pull everything. So I added a static number for each line item so I could see what it wasn't pulling and everything showed up.
because of the length I can't post everything but this works

```
    SELECT  '5' AS lineitem,`f`.`DWDOCID` AS `a`
 , DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%m/%d/%y') AS `B`
 , `f`.`FIELD_9` AS `C`
 , `f`.`VENDORCODE` AS `d`
 , `f`.`EMPLOYEENUMBER` AS `e`
 , `f`.`REMARKS` AS `f`
 , (CASE
         WHEN (`f`.`SHIPTO` = 'Broad Street Norwich') THEN 'Family Enrichment Network'
         WHEN (`f`.`SHIPTO` = 'DCMO Boces') THEN 'Family Enrichment Network'
         WHEN (`f`.`SHIPTO` = 'Cherry Street') THEN 'Family Enrichment Network'
         WHEN (`f`.`SHIPTO` = 'Carlisle') THEN 'Family Enrichment Network'
         WHEN (`f`.`SHIPTO` = 'Saratoga') THEN 'Family Enrichment Network'
         WHEN (`f`.`SHIPTO` = 'Wilson Elementary School') THEN 'Family Enrichment Network'
         WHEN (`f`.`SHIPTO` = 'Horrace Mann Elementary') THEN 'Family Enrichment Network'
         WHEN (`f`.`SHIPTO` = 'Fayette Street') THEN 'Family Enrichment Network'
         WHEN (`f`.`SHIPTO` = 'Newark Valley') THEN 'Family Enrichment Network'
         WHEN (`f`.`SHIPTO` = 'Owego') THEN 'Family Enrichment Network'
         WHEN (`f`.`SHIPTO` = 'Waverly') THEN 'Family Enrichment Network'
         WHEN (`f`.`SHIPTO` = 'Charles F. Johnson') THEN 'Family Enrichment Network'
    END) AS `shiptoname`
 , (CASE
         WHEN (`f`.`SHIPTO` = 'Broad Street Norwich') THEN '21 South Broad Street'
         WHEN (`f`.`SHIPTO` = 'DCMO Boces') THEN '6678 County Rd 32'
         WHEN (`f`.`SHIPTO` = 'Cherry Street') THEN '24 Cherry Street'
         WHEN (`f`.`SHIPTO` = 'Carlisle') THEN '150 Moeller St.'
         WHEN (`f`.`SHIPTO` = 'Saratoga') THEN '35 Felters Rd.'
         WHEN (`f`.`SHIPTO` = 'Wilson Elementary School') THEN '287 Prospect St.'
         WHEN (`f`.`SHIPTO` = 'Horrace Mann Elementary') THEN '30 College St.'
         WHEN (`f`.`SHIPTO` = 'Fayette Street') THEN '29 Fayette St.'
         WHEN (`f`.`SHIPTO` = 'Newark Valley') THEN '117 Whig St.'
         WHEN (`f`.`SHIPTO` = 'Owego') THEN '1277 Taylor Rd.'
         WHEN (`f`.`SHIPTO` = 'Waverly') THEN '12 Cooper St.'
         WHEN (`f`.`SHIPTO` = 'Charles F. Johnson') THEN '1201 Union Center Maine Highway'
    END) AS `address`
 , (CASE
         WHEN (`f`.`SHIPTO` = 'Broad Street Norwich') THEN ''
         WHEN (`f`.`SHIPTO` = 'DCMO Boces') THEN ''
         WHEN (`f`.`SHIPTO` = 'Cherry Street') THEN 'PO Box 997'
         WHEN (`f`.`SHIPTO` = 'Carlisle') THEN ''
         WHEN (`f`.`SHIPTO` = 'Saratoga') THEN 'Building 16'
         WHEN (`f`.`SHIPTO` = 'Wilson Elementary School') THEN ''
         WHEN (`f`.`SHIPTO` = 'Horrace Mann Elementary') THEN ''
         WHEN (`f`.`SHIPTO` = 'Fayette Street') THEN ''
         WHEN (`f`.`SHIPTO` = 'Newark Valley') THEN ''
         WHEN (`f`.`SHIPTO` = 'Owego') THEN ''
         WHEN (`f`.`SHIPTO` = 'Waverly') THEN ''
         WHEN (`f`.`SHIPTO` = 'Charles F. Johnson') THEN 'Linnaeus West Elementary School, Classroom 15'
    END) AS `address2`
 , (CASE
         WHEN (`f`.`SHIPTO` = 'Broad Street Norwich') THEN 'Norwich, NY 13815'
         WHEN (`f`.`SHIPTO` = 'DCMO Boces') THEN 'Norwich, NY 13815'
         WHEN (`f`.`SHIPTO` = 'Cherry Street') THEN 'Johnson City, NY 13790-0997'
         WHEN (`f`.`SHIPTO` = 'Carlisle') THEN 'Binghamton, NY 13904'
         WHEN (`f`.`SHIPTO` = 'Saratoga') THEN 'Binghamton, NY 13903'
         WHEN (`f`.`SHIPTO` = 'Wilson Elementary School') THEN 'Binghamton, NY 13905'
         WHEN (`f`.`SHIPTO` = 'Horrace Mann Elementary') THEN 'Binghamton, NY 13905'
         WHEN (`f`.`SHIPTO` = 'Fayette Street') THEN 'Binghamton, NY 13901'
         WHEN (`f`.`SHIPTO` = 'Newark Valley') THEN 'Newark Valley, NY 13811'
         WHEN (`f`.`SHIPTO` = 'Owego') THEN 'Owego, NY 13827'
         WHEN (`f`.`SHIPTO` = 'Waverly') THEN 'Waverly, NY 14892'
         WHEN (`f`.`SHIPTO` = 'Charles F. Johnson') THEN 'Endicott, NY 13760'
    END) AS `citystatezip`
 , 'Best Way' AS `BestWay`
 , DATE_FORMAT(`f`.`DATENEEDED`, '%m/%d/%y') AS `date_format(f.DATENEEDED,'%m/%d/%y')`
 , (`f`.`Q5` * 0.01) AS `q5`
 , `f`.`DES5` AS `DES5`
 , (`f`.`UPRICE5` / 100) AS `f.UPRICE5/100`
 , '0' AS `0`
 , 0 AS `f.shipping/100`
 , `f`.`DWDOCID` AS `DWDOCID`
 , '0' AS `My_exp_1_0`
 , '0' AS `My_exp_2_0`
 , '0' AS `My_exp_3_0`
 , `f`.`GLCODE5` AS `GLCODE`
 , `f`.`ELEMENT5` AS `ELEMENT`
 , ((`f`.`UPRICE5` / 100) * (`f`.`Q5` * 0.01)) AS `amount`
 , 'm:\\nbush.jpg' AS `Y`
 , DATE_FORMAT(`f`.`APPROVALDATE`, '%m/%d/%y') AS `Approvaldate`
 , 'm:\\blank.jpg' AS `AA`
 , REPLACE(LEFT(`f`.`VENDOR`, 20), '#N/A', '') AS `replace(left(``f``.``vendor``,20),'#N/A','')`
    FROM `dwdata`.`purchase_orders` `f`
    WHERE ((`f`.`DOCUMENT_TYPE` = 'REQUISITION FOR PURCHASE ORDER')
AND (`f`.`FIELD_9` = 'Executive Director Approved')
   AND (`f`.`EXECUTIVEDIRECTORAPPROVED` = 'Approved')
AND (`f`.`FISCALOFFICERAPPROVED` = 'Approved')
AND (`f`.`PROGRAMDIRECTORAPPROVED` = 'Approved')

AND (`f`.`Q5` IS NOT NULL))
```

This does not

```
    SELECT `f`.`DWDOCID` AS `a`
 , DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%m/%d/%y') AS `B`
 , `f`.`FIELD_9` AS `C`
 , `f`.`VENDORCODE` AS `d`
 , `f`.`EMPLOYEENUMBER` AS `e`
 , `f`.`REMARKS` AS `f`
 , (CASE
         WHEN (`f`.`SHIPTO` = 'Broad Street Norwich') THEN 'Family Enrichment Network'
         WHEN (`f`.`SHIPTO` = 'DCMO Boces') THEN 'Family Enrichment Network'
         WHEN (`f`.`SHIPTO` = 'Cherry Street') THEN 'Family Enrichment Network'
         WHEN (`f`.`SHIPTO` = 'Carlisle') THEN 'Family Enrichment Network'
         WHEN (`f`.`SHIPTO` = 'Saratoga') THEN 'Family Enrichment Network'
         WHEN (`f`.`SHIPTO` = 'Wilson Elementary School') THEN 'Family Enrichment Network'
         WHEN (`f`.`SHIPTO` = 'Horrace Mann Elementary') THEN 'Family Enrichment Network'
         WHEN (`f`.`SHIPTO` = 'Fayette Street') THEN 'Family Enrichment Network'
         WHEN (`f`.`SHIPTO` = 'Newark Valley') THEN 'Family Enrichment Network'
         WHEN (`f`.`SHIPTO` = 'Owego') THEN 'Family Enrichment Network'
         WHEN (`f`.`SHIPTO` = 'Waverly') THEN 'Family Enrichment Network'
         WHEN (`f`.`SHIPTO` = 'Charles F. Johnson') THEN 'Family Enrichment Network'
    END) AS `shiptoname`
 , (CASE
         WHEN (`f`.`SHIPTO` = 'Broad Street Norwich') THEN '21 South Broad Street'
         WHEN (`f`.`SHIPTO` = 'DCMO Boces') THEN '6678 County Rd 32'
         WHEN (`f`.`SHIPTO` = 'Cherry Street') THEN '24 Cherry Street'
         WHEN (`f`.`SHIPTO` = 'Carlisle') THEN '150 Moeller St.'
         WHEN (`f`.`SHIPTO` = 'Saratoga') THEN '35 Felters Rd.'
         WHEN (`f`.`SHIPTO` = 'Wilson Elementary School') THEN '287 Prospect St.'
         WHEN (`f`.`SHIPTO` = 'Horrace Mann Elementary') THEN '30 College St.'
         WHEN (`f`.`SHIPTO` = 'Fayette Street') THEN '29 Fayette St.'
         WHEN (`f`.`SHIPTO` = 'Newark Valley') THEN '117 Whig St.'
         WHEN (`f`.`SHIPTO` = 'Owego') THEN '1277 Taylor Rd.'
         WHEN (`f`.`SHIPTO` = 'Waverly') THEN '12 Cooper St.'
         WHEN (`f`.`SHIPTO` = 'Charles F. Johnson') THEN '1201 Union Center Maine Highway'
    END) AS `address`
 , (CASE
         WHEN (`f`.`SHIPTO` = 'Broad Street Norwich') THEN ''
         WHEN (`f`.`SHIPTO` = 'DCMO Boces') THEN ''
         WHEN (`f`.`SHIPTO` = 'Cherry Street') THEN 'PO Box 997'
         WHEN (`f`.`SHIPTO` = 'Carlisle') THEN ''
         WHEN (`f`.`SHIPTO` = 'Saratoga') THEN 'Building 16'
         WHEN (`f`.`SHIPTO` = 'Wilson Elementary School') THEN ''
         WHEN (`f`.`SHIPTO` = 'Horrace Mann Elementary') THEN ''
         WHEN (`f`.`SHIPTO` = 'Fayette Street') THEN ''
         WHEN (`f`.`SHIPTO` = 'Newark Valley') THEN ''
         WHEN (`f`.`SHIPTO` = 'Owego') THEN ''
         WHEN (`f`.`SHIPTO` = 'Waverly') THEN ''
         WHEN (`f`.`SHIPTO` = 'Charles F. Johnson') THEN 'Linnaeus West Elementary School, Classroom 15'
    END) AS `address2`
 , (CASE
         WHEN (`f`.`SHIPTO` = 'Broad Street Norwich') THEN 'Norwich, NY 13815'
         WHEN (`f`.`SHIPTO` = 'DCMO Boces') THEN 'Norwich, NY 13815'
         WHEN (`f`.`SHIPTO` = 'Cherry Street') THEN 'Johnson City, NY 13790-0997'
         WHEN (`f`.`SHIPTO` = 'Carlisle') THEN 'Binghamton, NY 13904'
         WHEN (`f`.`SHIPTO` = 'Saratoga') THEN 'Binghamton, NY 13903'
         WHEN (`f`.`SHIPTO` = 'Wilson Elementary School') THEN 'Binghamton, NY 13905'
         WHEN (`f`.`SHIPTO` = 'Horrace Mann Elementary') THEN 'Binghamton, NY 13905'
         WHEN (`f`.`SHIPTO` = 'Fayette Street') THEN 'Binghamton, NY 13901'
         WHEN (`f`.`SHIPTO` = 'Newark Valley') THEN 'Newark Valley, NY 13811'
         WHEN (`f`.`SHIPTO` = 'Owego') THEN 'Owego, NY 13827'
         WHEN (`f`.`SHIPTO` = 'Waverly') THEN 'Waverly, NY 14892'
         WHEN (`f`.`SHIPTO` = 'Charles F. Johnson') THEN 'Endicott, NY 13760'
    END) AS `citystatezip`
 , 'Best Way' AS `BestWay`
 , DATE_FORMAT(`f`.`DATENEEDED`, '%m/%d/%y') AS `date_format(f.DATENEEDED,'%m/%d/%y')`
 , (`f`.`Q5` * 0.01) AS `q5`
 , `f`.`DES5` AS `DES5`
 , (`f`.`UPRICE5` / 100) AS `f.UPRICE5/100`
 , '0' AS `0`
 , 0 AS `f.shipping/100`
 , `f`.`DWDOCID` AS `DWDOCID`
 , '0' AS `My_exp_1_0`
 , '0' AS `My_exp_2_0`
 , '0' AS `My_exp_3_0`
 , `f`.`GLCODE5` AS `GLCODE`
 , `f`.`ELEMENT5` AS `ELEMENT`
 , ((`f`.`UPRICE5` / 100) * (`f`.`Q5` * 0.01)) AS `amount`
 , 'm:\\nbush.jpg' AS `Y`
 , DATE_FORMAT(`f`.`APPROVALDATE`, '%m/%d/%y') AS `Approvaldate`
 , 'm:\\blank.jpg' AS `AA`
 , REPLACE(LEFT(`f`.`VENDOR`, 20), '#N/A', '') AS `replace(left(``f``.``vendor``,20),'#N/A','')`
     FROM `dwdata`.`purchase_orders` `f`
     WHERE ((`f`.`DOCUMENT_TYPE` = 'REQUISITION FOR PURCHASE ORDER')
AND (`f`.`FIELD_9` = 'Executive Director Approved')
    AND (`f`.`EXECUTIVEDIRECTORAPPROVED` = 'Approved')
AND (`f`.`FISCALOFFICERAPPROVED` = 'Approved')
AND (`f`.`PROGRAMDIRECTORAPPROVED` = 'Approved')
AND (`f`.`Q5` IS NOT NULL))
```

Any idea why not? It is exactly the same code except for the line item.

Comment: Just to clarify. These two statements are identical except for `'5' AS lineitem`. Like you get a different record count? You say you aren't posting all of the code for this SQL statement so I suspect the issue is in someting you aren't including here since merely adding that `lineitem` constant to your select clause couldn't possibly account for this behavior alone given the SQL you have posted.

Comment: for each section before the union I had added a line item so that each record would be forced to be unique. That solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I did not realize that a union will not retrieve duplicate records. If the person filling out the PO did what any normal person would have done and just said a quantity 2 for one line item and quantity of 3 for another line item instead of having 5 line items with a quantity of 1 when there were only 2 unique items it would not have been a problem.